# read data from a stream in ruby

Tags: ruby, stream

I have to run `top` in my machine (mac osx), and get the cpu usage from there, in real time.
How can I do that?
I tried running top and saving it but it must end before it saves it.

Thank you.

Comment: Didn't you already ask this question?  Searching for "cpu top ruby" yields a question you'd recently asked which seems very similar if not identical.

Comment: I'd say it's a different question. The first was basically "how can I keep from having to use top", while this is "ok, if I have to use top, how do I do it?"

Comment: Although the answer (i.e. just run top -n 1) is really the answer to both... hm.

Comment: yes kshep.. excactly. I didn't find a better way to do what I need from the previous question, so I have to do it with `top`. I tried -n, but I am on a mac, and -n here is the number of processes to display.

Comment: hm.. just found out that -l is the -n for mac. so `top -l 1 -n 0` gives me just one frame, with zero processes, so I get just the stuff I need. cpu usage and all that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The -n command line option lets you run top for the specified number of cycles, then exit. So `top -n 1` just runs it once and you can parse the output.

Comment: On what OS? In Linux -n is the number of iterations.